# how to add database Table to custom form and show the result in webpage

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, forms

As a beginner i am really struggling lot in PHP . I have a problem Pls help me out.
    1- I am try to create a Custom Form and get the data from user in my webpage using wp.
    2-I need to Store the data that user entered in the form By creating Database Table.
    3- I really dont no how to  Display the data that have been Stored in Tabe. I will Give ma code

```
1-  FORM::::::::
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">

Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

</form>

</body>
</html>

2- jUST cHECKING tHE DATA.
<form action="NewDB.php" method="POST">

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br>
</form>
tHESE TWO ARE WORKING MY PROB IS WITH THE DATABE.PHP
3- This program is giving error

<form action="image.php" method="POST">
    <form action="image.php" method="post">
        <?php
$con=mysql_connect('may.org.in'," "," ","mydb");// wHAT I HAVE TO PROVIDE HERE??? tHIS IS ERROR
if(mysql_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed to connect";

}
$db="CREATE DATABASE mydb";
if(mysqli_query($con,$db))
{
    echo"connected";

}else
{
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
$tab="CREATE TABLE Persons(name CHAR(30),email CHAR(30))";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($con,$tab))
  {
  echo "Table persons created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, email)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";



if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
//echo "1 record added";

//mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
    <table border="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      //<th>Email Id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      if( mysql_num_rows( $selectRes )==0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="4">No Rows Returned</td></tr>';
      }else{
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql) ){
          echo "<tr><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['email']}</td></tr>\n";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table></form>

4- fINALLY TELL ME HOW TO SHOW THE DATA IN MY WEBPAGE. pLS dO HELP ME!!
```

Comment: You should first read the PHP documentation on the commands you have questions with. For example mysql_connect (btw use mysqli!) is completelyexplained there. The comments also show plenty of samples.

Answer (score 0):

In $con you need to provide ('server name','username','your password').

In $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (name, email)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";

add single quotes and curly brackets to the values, like {$_POST['name']}.

To display data on webpage you need to call your database using a mysql_query() function and mysql_fetch_array() function.

I think you need to learn the basics and syntax before trying to create usable work.

Yes, use mysqli please. Save the headache.

Comment: And please also read about SQL injections and why mysql is no longer in use. This is a major issue if you plan to go live with your script.